# Prisma Adapter not updating MongoDb data

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am trying to store access token and all other details given by user in MongoDB using Prisma Adapter by Next Auth.

The issue is the database store all the user and account details on the initial sign in but when the user signs in again it is not updating the user and account data like new access token value,updated at value. Below is my code :

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import prisma from '../../../libs/prismadb'
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { SessionStrategy } from "next-auth";

export const authOptions = {
adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
providers: \[

        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,            
        }),        
    ],
    database: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    secret: process.env.NEXT_AUTH_SECRET,
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt" as SessionStrategy,
    },

}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export { handler as GET, handler as POST}`
```

I implemented it as per the docs.